# Selenium doesn't load the complete page

Tags: python, selenium, screen-scraping

I'm trying to scrape this site:

https://www.lobstersnowboards.com/shop/eiki-pro-model--459

And one of the fields I want to get is the available models:

[image]

But this part is not getting loaded by selenium:

[image]

I had tried with both, firefox and chrome, getting the same result.

Comment: I see no models even without using Selenium

Comment: Ah I was seeing both the page and the dropdown with models in Chrome 65, but just upgraded to Chrome 66, now getting `NET::ERR_CERT_SYMANTEC_LEGACY` error. Could it be certificate-related?

Comment: @MichalCharemza that is using selenium? In scrapy doesn't work either

Comment: @LuisRamonRamirezRodriguez That was just loading up manually. However, now in Chrome 66 using Selenium, it does load, with the models drop down, but with a red "Not secure" warning on the left of the address bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue that it doesn't work is not related to Selenium.

It is because of localization. As you can see in your top bar `REST OF THE WORLD` and you are not in `United States` which should show you the US prices

Below script shows how it works

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.lobstersnowboards.com/shop/eiki-pro-model--459")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[title='Rest of the World'] span.caret").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[.='United States']").click()
import time
time.sleep(4)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.options [title='Select'] span.caret").click()
elems = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.options ul > li a span")
for elem in elems:
    print(elem.text.strip())
```

I have used a dirty quick sleep, which you should not but that is just for the demo

[image: Output]

And below is the actual page in the chrome

[image: Select Options]

**Somethings that will impact you later but not in Chrome 65**

> On January 19, 2017, a public posting to the mozilla.dev.security.policy newsgroup drew attention to a series of questionable website authentication certificates issued by Symantec Corporation’s PKI. Symantec’s PKI business, which operates a series of Certificate Authorities under various brand names, including Thawte, VeriSign, Equifax, GeoTrust, and RapidSSL, had issued numerous certificates that did not comply with the industry-developed CA/Browser Forum Baseline Requirements. During the subsequent investigation, it was revealed that Symantec had entrusted several organizations with the ability to issue certificates without the appropriate or necessary oversight, and had been aware of security deficiencies at these organizations for some time.

From: https://security.googleblog.com/2017/09/chromes-plan-to-distrust-symantec.html

> The SSL certificate used to load resources from https://www.lobstersnowboards.com will be distrusted in M66. Once distrusted, users will be prevented from loading these resources. See https://g.co/chrome/symantecpkicerts for more information.

This is the error that is shown in `Chrome 65`.

Comment: Which will be an option for the delay?

Comment: You will use the `WebDriverWait` for the same on this element `driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.options [title='Select'] span.caret")`. What's called a explicit wait in Python Selenium